# Ubuntu 20.04 slow after idle

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 is slow after some idle time.

When I again start using PC, it return back to normal after couple of minutes.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

I have 8 GB DDR2 RAM memory, it is usually 50% used.

Comment: You've provided little to go with.. Are you talking about Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, Ubuntu 20.04 Server etc.. what apps.. have you tried to explore possible causes?   On my own system I'd fine this desktop *thrashing* (out of memory & swapping to disk) at certain times.. and using `htop` I was able to work out it was the browsers (`chromium` or `firefox`)... and for me quitting the program, then re-starting it fixes the issue. On further examination I found it was an extension (I use in both), but as I want that extension, I just deal with it (quit program, let OS recover ram, then re-start prog)

Comment: Your issue may not be browser/ram/thrashing like my example... but tools like `htop` and the like may provide clues.. as does being specific with details (server? desktop? what do you use it for?  "*start using pc it return back to normal*" yet no mention of what it was doing before then?  screensaver? calculations or computations? etc

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons why it would get slower.  Either there is a power management tool that is throttling down cpu speed and possibly other resources, or you have a background task (like perhaps unattended upgrades or updatedb) that is using system resources and making the rest of system sluggish.

If it is power management that makes it slow, performance should resume to normal when you start using the system.  You can also change your power profile to get faster response.  A tool like the ubuntu package indicator-cpufreq or the gnome shell extension cpufreq, both of which can both show you current cpu frequency settings and allow you to pick a profile.

If a background job is slowing down your system, you should be able to see it in one of the system monitoring tools.  Either a text terminal based monitor (top, htop, atop, systemd-cgtop) or a graphical tool (qtop, gnome-system-monitor, ksysguard) should help you spot what is using your system resources.   If it is a normal background job started by the system, eventually it should finish and performance should return to normal.  Note that systemd-cgtop can show activity associated with specific system services rather than just the resulting processes.  However, it could be some application causing it, which you may want to stop or remove.

Comment: Thank you for helping.

I did not have any additonal software installed.

Now I installed pm-utils and I set pm-powersave to false.

Now I wait some time to see what will happen.